# notifications pop up in user side

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i am trying to show notification as a pop up. like when admin login and through his account he send notification to user. i have added this html in  admin form like this..

```
<asp:Button ID="notic" runat="server" Text="Send" onclick="Button1_Click" /> <br />

          <input class="add_message" type="text" value="type your message"
          name="add_message"></input>
  <input type="button" value="add message"  
        onclick="sNotify.addToQueue($('.add_message').attr('value'))"/>
```

Then when admin click on button then notification send to users account like when any user login then he/she able to see pop ups in user form 
I call this java script in user form page load like this ..

```
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Javascript",
          "javascript:sNotify.addToQueue($('.add_message').attr('value'))();", true);
```

it works like when i login as an admin and click on button then notification appear in his own page ..
but  i want to show this notifications in userform.

so how can i get this??

Comment: You want the admin to be able to send a notification to a user? Take a look at [SignalR](http://signalr.net/).

Comment: yes... this is sginalIR is so complicated :/